# How to change endpoint address for multiple tests?

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

I know how to change endpoint for each test, but I have 100+ tests so I would like to select project/all tests and say set new endpoint. Is it posible?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Yes it is possible!

Double-click on your WSDL interface in the Navigator view on the left.

Then select the second tab called *Service Endpoints*. Select the desired endpoint (or add it first via the "+"-symbol) and click *Assign*. There you select *All Requests and TestRequests*.

Comment: Wow, didn't know this though using soapUI Pro since version 2.x :-)

Comment: FYI, the option 'All Requests and TestRequests' is in the top of the drop down menu. Because I had a fairly high list of endpoints, I didn't find it at first. Also, when launching a TestRunner you can override the endpoint there too.

Answer (score 4):

You could also set up a 'centralized' endpoint prefix as described here: http://www.soapui.org/Functional-Testing/working-with-properties.html#4-example-n-centralized-endpoint

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there is no way to do this in soapUI itself. However you could try the following:

- Save your project and close soapUI.
- Open the XML file of your project in a text editor.
- Search for `<con:endpoint>` which contains the URL for the endpoint.
- Replace the endpoint in the text editor.

This, of course, only works if the endpoint you'd like to change is identical for all soapUI artefacts.

Answer (score 0):

From soapUI 4.5 a new feature called "Environments" has been added to soapUI Pro. It is quite handy and pretty much allows you what you are trying to achieve here.

Once you configure all your environments and corresponding endpoints it is a matter of selecting environment from the dropdown when you run testSuite/testCase. You can add as many environments you want. This way you need not to update anything when you want to flip environment.